# How to store request parameter in cache

Tags: spring-boot

I want to store my request in cache for the future reference because my method is void. I don't know how. My methods syntax is:

```
@CacheEvict(key="Key",value="AirSegment",beforeInvocation=true)
    private void cahingAndStoringSegment(String Key,TypeBaseAirSegment AirSegment){
    --- doing some operation
}
```

I am new in spring boot so please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you are trying to do.  Usually you use the @Cacheable attribute to prevent your method from going to a slow backend resource on each invocation. The @Cacheable annotation uses all the method arguments as the key. However since your operation is void its unclear what you are trying to cache.

@CacheEvict is used when you want invocation of a method to clear the cache.

There is also the @CachePut tag.  @CachePut(value=AirSegment,key=key) would add the the passed AirSegment in your operation to the cache.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable

If you think of a CRUD operation,  the @Cachable would be used on the Read operations, and the @CacheEvict on the Create, Update and Delete operations.